# How hot should I let a GridSeed IC get?

Tags: temperature, overclocking, overheating

I have a Gridseed Scrypt-based crypto miner with a very noisy fan. I've read a few pieces that state the device can be run without a heat sync or fan, so I went out and bought a Fluke infrared thermometer to monitor the temp as I try this suggestion out. How hot should should I let the surface of the chip run before ending my experiment?

Comment: That depends entirely on how long you plan to use your miner ...

Comment: @EugenRieck At least a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [spec sheet](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxFU17PfhOeeaEVlM3Q1VDBlUkU/edit) says that the chip is rated to operate at up to 85C. The surface of the package will tend to be a bit cooler than the chip itself, so I'd say 70C is a good safe limit.